# Find if $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x}{1+x^2\sin^2{x}}dx$ converges or diverges

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, limits, definite-integrals

Find if $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x}{1+x^2\sin^2{x}}dx$ converges or diverges
What I think should be right solution here is to replace $\sin^2{x}$ with 1 as long as it is the maximum value of $\sin^2{x}$ in the given bounds.
Still, that gives me no actual solution and I don't know the next steps

Comment: This is not an improper integral!

Comment: Note that $$
1 + x^2 \sin ^2 x \ge 1 \Rightarrow \frac{x}{{1 + x^2 \sin ^2 x}} \le x.
$$

Comment: $f= \frac{x}{1+x^2\sin^2 x}$ is continuos on $[0,π] $Hence?

Comment: Sorry, there was a mistake in the original question. It is the $+\infty$ which the upper bound

Comment: It is not proper to make a non-trivial change in question after an answer is posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integral does not converge as $$\int_0^\infty \frac{x}{1+x^2\sin^2 x}dx\ge \int_0^\infty \frac{x}{1+x^2}dx=\frac{\ln(1+x^2)}{2}\mid_{0}^{\infty}=\infty.$$